# MySql comma seperated values and using IN to select data

Tags: mysql

I store destinations a user is willing to ship a product to in a varchar field like this:

```
"userId" "destinations" "product"
"1"      "US,SE,DE"     "apples"
"2"      "US,SE"        "books"
"3"      "US"           "mushrooms"
"1"      "SE,DE"        "figs"
"2"      "UK"           "Golf Balls"
```

I was hoping this query would return all rows where `US` was present. Instead it returns only a single row.

```
select * from destinations where destinations IN('US');
```

How do I get this right? Am I using the wrong column type? or is it my query that's failing.

**Current Results**

```
US
```

**Expected Results**

```
US,SE,DE
US,SE
US
```

Comment: First normalise your data

Comment: I recommend you to put the destinations into table inside `[..]` characters like `[US][SE][DE]` then you can get the records that contain `US` by doing `SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE destinations LIKE ('%[US]%')`

Comment: @Strawberry Each row belongs to a particular user. UserId 1 will ship to the US,SE,DE... and so on.

Comment: Yes. Hence the requirement to normalise.

Comment: @Strawberry And In this case I'd have to?

Comment: You'd have a table called something like user_destination which would pair up each user with each of their respective destinations.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually, I did not mention that in the question, since I only wanted to know how to use IN. Each row is a product posted by each user (see edit). A user can choose which countries he's willing to ship each product to. It will not be the same for all products. So that's the reason I kept things this way. Still normalize?

Comment: @Norman - I updated my design to address your latest schema updates.  You want 2 tables - products and product_destinations.  Cheeers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with FIND_IN_SET

```
select * from destinations where FIND_IN_SET('US',destinations);
```

Comment: +1 for an interesting solution.  However, the problem with this is that as you add countries to your search, you have to compound the query with additional FIND_IN_SET matches. which is terrible for performance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the way you've structured your table, you'll have to check for a pattern match for "US" in your string at the beginning, middle, or end.

One way you can do that is using LIKE, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM destinations 
WHERE destinations LIKE ('%US%');
```

Another way is using REGEXP:

```
SELECT * 
FROM destinations 
WHERE destinations REGEXP '.*US.*';
```

Yet another is using FIND_IN_SET, as explained by Sadkhasan.

**CAVEAT**

None of these will offer great performance or data integrity, though.  And they will all COMPOUND their performance problems when you add criteria to your search.

E.g. using FIND_IN_SET, proposed by Sadkhasan, you would have to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM destinations 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('US',destinations)
    OR FIND_IN_SET('CA',destinations)
    OR FIND_IN_SET('ET',destinations);
```

Using REGEXP is a little better, though REGEXP is innately slow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM destinations 
WHERE destinations REGEXP '.*US|CA|ET.*';
```

**SO WHAT NOW?**

Your best bet would be switching to a 3NF design with destinations applying to products by splitting into 2 tables that you can join, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    userId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Then you would add what's called a composite key table, each row containing a productId and a single country, with one row per country.

```
CREATE TABLE product_destinations (
    productId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES products(id),
    country VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIARY KEY (productId, country)
) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Data in this table would look like:

```
productId | country
----------|--------
        1 | US
        1 | CA
        1 | ET
        2 | US
        2 | GB
```

Then you could structure a query like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products AS p
    INNER JOIN product_destinations AS d
        ON p.id = d.productId
WHERE d.country IN ('US', 'CA', 'ET')
GROUP BY p.id;
```

It's important to add the GROUP (or DISTINCT in the SELECT clause), as a single product may ship to multiple countries, resulting in multiple row matches - aggregation will reduce those to a single result per product id.

An added bonus is you don't have to UPDATE your countries column and do string operations to determine if the country already exists there.  You can let the database do that for you, and INSERT - preventing locking issues that will further compound your problems.

Comment: what if it only contains just 'US' ? This code doesnt retrieve it, does it?

Comment: I can make changes, since this is the beginning. What are you suggesting?

Comment: I strongly suggest you read up on 3NF design, and structure your database that way, to optimize for performance as well as for data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if your destinations have just two caracters of the countries.

```
    SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE  destinations LIKE ('%US%')
```

to add other country

```
    SELECT * FROM destinations WHERE  destinations LIKE ('%US%')
                                 AND  destinations LIKE ('%SE%') 
                                 ^^^--> you use AND or OR as you want the result.
```